# How to pass a python variable to a MS SQL SELECT instruction?

Tags: python, sql, variables

**Why this code returns nothing?**

```
ip = '10.113.205.55'

cursor.execute("Select * from tablename WHERE ip like '%s' "), ip

result = cursor.fetchall()

print result
```

**when i use the code below it works:**

```
cursor.execute("Select * from tablename where ip like '10.113.205.55' ")

result = cursor.fetchall()

print result
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the argument of cursor.execute method to:`cursor.execute("Select * from tablename WHERE ip like '%s'" % ip)`

Comment: OMG, how i didnt see that... It Works now, thnx!

Comment: But look at @Daniel answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `'` and put ip inside the parameter list:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ip LIKE %s", [ip])
```